# 4 input multiplexer in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, multiplexer

I am trying to model a 4 input multiplexer using VHDL; I am using edaplayground.com. I am trying to do this using a 2 input multiplexer. The code for only the 2 input multiplexer works, but when I try the 4 input multiplexer I get a lot of errors. This example is almost exactly what is in my textbook. Do you see what is wrong here?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mux2 is
    port(d0, d1: in STD_LOGIC;
         s:      in STD_LOGIC;
         y:     out STD_LOGIC);
end;

architecture synth of mux2 is
begin
    y<= d1 when s='1' else d0;
end;

entity mux4 is
    port(d0,d1,d2,d3: in STD_LOGIC;
         s: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
         y: out STD_LOGIC);
end;

architecture struct of mux4 is
    component mux2
        port(d0, d1: in STD_LOGIC;
            s: in STD_LOGIC;
            y: out STD_LOGIC);
    end component;
    signal low, high: STD_LOGIC;
begin
        lowmux: mux2 port map(d0, d1, s(0), low);
        highmux: mux2 port map(d2, d3, s(0), high);
        finalmux: mux2 port map(low, high, s(1), y);
end;
```

The error-messages I get is:

```
design.vhd:16:26: no declaration for "std_logic"
design.vhd:17:16: no declaration for "std_logic_vector"
design.vhd:18:17: no declaration for "std_logic"
design.vhd:23:25: no declaration for "std_logic"
design.vhd:24:19: no declaration for "std_logic"
design.vhd:25:20: no declaration for "std_logic"
design.vhd:27:23: no declaration for "std_logic"
design.vhd:29:9: for default port binding of component instance "lowmux":
design.vhd:29:9: type of signal interface "d0" declared at line 23:14
design.vhd:29:9: not compatible with type of port "d0" declared at line 5:10
design.vhd:29:9: type of signal interface "d1" declared at line 23:18
design.vhd:29:9: not compatible with type of port "d1" declared at line 5:14
design.vhd:29:9: type of signal interface "s" declared at line 24:13
design.vhd:29:9: not compatible with type of port "s" declared at line 6:10
design.vhd:29:9: type of signal interface "y" declared at line 25:13
design.vhd:29:9: not compatible with type of port "y" declared at line 7:10
design.vhd:30:9: for default port binding of component instance "highmux":
design.vhd:30:9: type of signal interface "d0" declared at line 23:14
design.vhd:30:9: not compatible with type of port "d0" declared at line 5:10
design.vhd:30:9: type of signal interface "d1" declared at line 23:18
design.vhd:30:9: not compatible with type of port "d1" declared at line 5:14
design.vhd:30:9: type of signal interface "s" declared at line 24:13
design.vhd:30:9: not compatible with type of port "s" declared at line 6:10
design.vhd:30:9: type of signal interface "y" declared at line 25:13
design.vhd:30:9: not compatible with type of port "y" declared at line 7:10
design.vhd:31:9: for default port binding of component instance "finalmux":
design.vhd:31:9: type of signal interface "d0" declared at line 23:14
design.vhd:31:9: not compatible with type of port "d0" declared at line 5:10
design.vhd:31:9: type of signal interface "d1" declared at line 23:18
design.vhd:31:9: not compatible with type of port "d1" declared at line 5:14
design.vhd:31:9: type of signal interface "s" declared at line 24:13
design.vhd:31:9: not compatible with type of port "s" declared at line 6:10
design.vhd:31:9: type of signal interface "y" declared at line 25:13
design.vhd:31:9: not compatible with type of port "y" declared at line 7:10
```

The link to edaplayground is:

https://edaplayground.com/x/w3By

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat the lines:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
```

Like this (before the second entity):

[image]

Which works when elaborating 'mux4':

[image]